# C++ Classes, Pointers, Constructors, Segmentation Faults, 2D arrays

Tags: c++, class, pointers, header-files, class-constructors

.h file

```
public:
Class(int x, int y); //constructor for this question

private:
char (*1dArrayObjectPtr)[size] = nullptr;
char nameof2dArray[notImportantX][size];
```

What is the difference between initializing `Class (*1dArrayObjectPtr)[size] = nullptr;` then assigning by:

cpp file

```
Class::Class(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {1dArrayObjectPtr = nameOf2dArray;};
```

or:

```
Class::Class(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y), 1DArrayObjectPtr(nameof2dArray) {};
```

Why does the top option result in segmentation faults and the bottom does not when I access as:

`*(*(1DArrayObjectPtr+i)+j)`
or
`1DArrayObject[i][j]`

If I pass `1DArrayObjectPtr` to a new class will I be able to iterate the same?:

```
newClass::newClass(char* 1DArrayObjectPtr) : newClassPtr(1DArrayObjectPtr) {};
```

iterate as `*(*(newClassPtr+i)+j)`   or  `newClassPtr[i][j]`

Or am I changing the 1dpointer from the 2D array into something else and not realizing?

Comment: Thank you MikeCAT for the format assistance!

Comment: `1dArrayObjectPtr` is definitely not a valid identifier in C++. (This cannot crash -> this cannot run -> this doesn't compile.)

Comment: I know. It is meant as the idea of something not a literal name.

Comment: This is a concepts question

Comment: I made a [mcve]. There is actually no difference between initialization of member and assignment of member in constructor (concerning the result after construction): [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2e20d61c28e65cb) Maybe, I got your question wrong...

Comment: I mean you addressed some of the confusion. But If there is no difference between initialization of member vs assignment, then why is the behavior different when using *(*(1DArrayObjectPtr+i)+j) or 1DArrayObject[i][j] , pending on if the member is initialized or assigned? There 'should' be no difference as you say. I understand that. But there is different behavior and I don't understand why. Maybe there is a pointer semantic or relevance I am missing.

Comment: That's why a [mcve] is preferable over "meant concepts". Maybe, the error is caused by something else and you're searching in a wrong direction.

Comment: `a[b]` and `(*a + b)` are semantically equivalent. (Maybe, I overlooked certain corner cases e.g. with overloaded operators or whatever.) However, in the case of my mcve, they are in fact equivalent: [**Demo 2.0 on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f83343aeb8a391a3),

Answer (score 0):

Scheff has confirmed semantically, there is no difference. I will look to my constructors for the base class to see if they could be culprit. Thanks Scheff. I tried to mark your comment as a solution, but I may have flagged it by mistake.... :D